# Can I connect 2 android application without a server

Tags: android, sockets, server

I am trying to develop two android application that can exchange data  without server. So please suggest how can I do this. Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I connect two Android device by socket without server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29163381/how-can-i-connect-two-android-device-by-socket-without-server)

Comment: 2 android apps on the same device ? or two different devices?

Comment: @ADM - that link only works where the devices are on mutually routable networks, which is not usually the case - mobile networks won't typically allow inbound connections.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways:

- Send intents, receive via intent filters
- Use local sockets
- Store data on SD card (only recommended if you already require the permission for other functionality)

I would probably go for the intents if there are only small, occasional messages to exchange.
Intents work on a higher abstraction level and do things like launching the target activity.
If you are using sockets, then you might have to implement more configuration and error handling.

Comment: I'm not sure if OP was mention if 2 apps are on the same device ... if NOT then this answer will obviosuly not apply

Answer (score 0):

If you mean connection via socket you can look into the [ServerSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html). Alternatively,
you can use a "server less" platform like [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) or [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) and exchange database data between these two devices.

Comment: *...server less platform like AWS or Firebase*  ... yeah, for sure they are server-less hahaha ...  *[using] ... ServerSocket* ... if devices are in the same local network then should be no problem ... but if they are on internet/3g/4g then good luck with punching the NAT

Comment: By definition, the application waiting on `ServerSocket.accept()` is a server.